# Parsing HTTP response with shell

Tags: shell, grep, curl

I want to parse below HTTP response but I cannot figure out how to grep the values separately using a single curl request.

I need these two output.
1. status_code - (Array of HTTP status codes)
2. exceptionMsg - (Occured exception in a variable)

```
 HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 173
    Connection: close

    {"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Failed to parse \"false?op=CREATE\" to Boolean."}}
```

I tried this

```
curl -i  -X PUT -T test1.txt "http request"| grep HTPP
curl -i  -X PUT -T test1.txt "http request" | grep Exception
```

How can I get this done in one command ?

Comment: what do you mean by *array of status codes*?

Comment: There will be more than one status code i want all of them..I might have used wrong term to explain it

Comment: where? in the HTTP response or in the JSON? the first line looks ok just a typo - you misspelled `HTTP`

Comment: the HTTP response will only have one status code per request. do you want to save the status code from each request into an array?

Comment: I'm getting two status codes/request I want both in one array

Answer (score 2):

`grep` supports regular expressions.
Example:

```
curl -i  -X PUT -T test1.txt "http request"|  grep -E "(HTTP|Exception)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the curl output to a temporary file, get your status codes then delete file.

```
...
# put response in a temporary file
curl -i http://www.example.com -o response.html

# initialise array to hold status_codes in
status_codes=()

status_codes+=$(sed -n "1p" response.html | grep -o "[[:digit:]]\{3\}")
status_codes+=($(sed -n "3p" response.html | grep -o "[[:digit:]]\{3\}"))
#                       ^ change this to the line numnber where the reponse code is

# print status_codes array (you probably want to comment this out)
declare -p status_codes

rm response.html
```